# How do you specify no vibrato in notation?

Tags: notation, string-instruments

I am composing a piece for string quartet, and I explicitly don't want vibrato. Is there a term for it, or should I just write "no vibrato"?

Comment: Oliver Knussen often used **_cool_** and **_warm_** in his string writing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would write *senza vibrato* (without vibrato) or *non vibrato* in the score. If you want vibrato to resume, use *con vibrato*.

Comment: @Neins Note, such markings are often used to indicate a particular brief passage be without vibrato (with the assumption that vibrato is always the default the rest of the time). If you want the entire piece to be without vibrato, you should put the marking at the very beginning; for a traditional Italian term, something like *siempre senza vibrato* (though I'm a fan of simply using the common language of the composer and intended musician market; in English, maybe something like "no vibrato throughout").

Comment: @AndyBonner _siempre_ is Spanish.  The Italian is _sempre._  (A good argument, perhaps, in favor of composers using their own language for such instructions.)

Comment: @phoog fortunately there won't be much meaning confusion between sempre/siempre and con/cum etc. – but for sure it's bound to make native speakers of each language cringe! I'd say it's best to just look up the spelling of such standard terms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_music_terminology If no standard term can be found, explain in English, but I'd prefer doing it in a prose explanation at the start of the piece, rather than putting in possibly ambiguous nonstandard short instructions in the middle of the score.

Comment: @phoog Oops, of course you're right (and I can't edit a comment). I'm always getting French in my Spanish and vice versa, so I guess some Spanish had to escape into Italian to make room.

Comment: @leftaroundabout And yes, +1 for: if something is really important to you, better to spell it out in a little explanatory introduction. I feel like there's an Arvo Pärt piece that gets specific about "maybe some vibrato, but only a little bit, not too big" or something like that.